# Cannot log in to the MySQL server/The target computer expressly refused

Tags: mysql, windows, phpmyadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdBHa.png)I have this error when i try to connect to my database knowing that I've already used it and everything was normal until the last update of windows10.
when i try to open the mysql command line it crashes. How can it fix that ?
i checked MYSQL80 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q0QJ.png)in the services and it running normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have that problem too, when I forget to disable my VPN.

> - Ensure you are not using any VPN
> - Ensure the credentials are correct
> - Ensure the antivirus/firewall is not blocking the connection
> - Ensure you can access PhpMyAdmin using XAMPP

If nothing works, contact the service provider, and ask them to allow you access to the database. Additionally, you can ask them to whitelist your IP address.

Comment: how can i know if the antivirus isnt blocking the connection ?

Comment: Can you first try accessing the PhpMyAdmin using XAMPP (make sure Apache and MySQL are enabled **Services**). for MySQL, click on the button "Admin" and see if it opens the page without problems. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: hey, my problem is solved so the problem was in Appserv for an uknown reason it stopped working so i had to update it and it's working (i lost my database but well). Thank you !

Comment: Oh, you use Appserv. I didn't consider that, well I am happy that my answer helped to guide you to tackle the issue :)